# Matrix multiplication using OpenMP parallel do does not improve execution time

Tags: fortran, openmp, gfortran

I'm starting to testing Openmp, but I don't get to improve execution time with this simple example. What should I change in my code?

The following code (prueba.f90) was compile with:

```
gfortran -Wall -fopenmp -g -o prog.exe prueba.f90 
./prog.exe
```

```
program main
use omp_lib
implicit none
integer, parameter:: ma=100, n=10000, mb= 100
real, dimension (ma,n) :: a 
real, dimension (n,mb) :: b
real, dimension (ma,mb) :: c = 0. 
integer:: i,j,k, num_threads=4
real:: toc, tic, time

call random_number (a)
call random_number (b)

  !$ call omp_set_num_threads(num_threads)

  call cpu_time(tic)

  !$omp paralleldo
  do i= 1,ma
    do j= 1,mb
      do k= 1,n
        c(i,j) = c(i,j) + a(i,k)*b(k,j)
      end do 
    end do
  end do 
  !$omp end paralleldo
  
  
call cpu_time(toc)
time = toc-tic 

print*, c(23,35) , 'time', time, 's'

end program main
```

Comment: cpu_time is NOT the right subroutine for parallel computing. Lots of duplicates.

Comment: @VladimirF Thank you so much that solve my problem.